# Unhover menus when sub-menu is collapsed

Tags: jquery, html, css

I developed the following simple jQuery menu:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".button, .button_menu_01").on('click', function () {
    
    var $panel = $(this).next('.panel');
    if ($panel.is(':visible')) {
      $panel.add($panel.find('.panel')).slideUp(500).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $panel.slideDown(500).addClass('active');
    }
    
    });
});
```

```css
.button {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 float: right;
 background-color: fuchsia;
}

.panel{ 
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 0%;
 font-weight: bold;
 overflow: hidden;
 display:none;
}

.button_menu_01 {
 padding-left: 1%;
 background: blue;
}

.button_menu_01:hover {
 background: #CCCCCC;
}

.active {
 background: #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">Menu</div>
  <div class="panel"> 
 
    <div class="button_menu_01">1.0 Main Menu</div>
    <div class="panel">
        
      <div>1.1 Sub Menu</div>
     
      <div class="button_menu_01">1.2 Sub Menu</div>
      <div class="panel">
  
        <div> 1.2.1 Sub Menu</div>
        <div> 1.2.2 Sub Menu</div>  

    </div> 
   
  </div>

</div>
```

You can also find the code in the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1sxfo9ka/2/). 
All this works fine so far.

---

Now, I want to achieve that the main menus which refer in my case to the class `.button_menu_01` remain hovered when the user navigates in the sub-menus. Once the user collapses the sub menus the hovering should also be deleted. Therefore, I tried to go with the `.active` class but now all the sub-menus are in colour `#CCCCCC`.

What do I have to change in my code to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

instead of assigning active class to submenu, assign active class to main menu item

try this js

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".button, .button_menu_01").on('click', function () {

```
var $panel = $(this).next('.panel');
if ($panel.is(':visible')) {
  $panel.add($panel.find('.panel')).slideUp(500,function(){
    $(".button").removeClass('active')
  });
} else {
  $panel.slideDown(500,function(){
    $(".button").addClass('active');
  })
}

});
});
```

see updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1sxfo9ka/20/)